# Queue connection to Oracle AQ : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection.getDbCsId()S

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle-aq

I have a problem when create connection to Oracle AQ with java.
Here the code :

```
TopicConnectionFactory tc_fact = null;
TopicConnection t_conn = null;
TopicSession t_sess = null;

String[] args = new String[6];
args[0] = "orcl"; // sid
args[1] = "192.168.1.253"; // hostname
args[2] = "1521"; // portno
args[3] = "thin"; // driver
args[4] = "arizona"; // user
args[5] = "arizona"; // pass

tc_fact = AQjmsFactory.getTopicConnectionFactory(args[1], args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[2]), args[3]);
t_conn = tc_fact.createTopicConnection(args[4], args[5]);
t_sess = t_conn.createTopicSession(true, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
t_conn.start();
```

I got error like this :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection.getDbCsId()S
 at oracle.jms.AQjmsSession.setDBRatio(AQjmsSession.java:571)
 at oracle.jms.AQjmsSession.<init>(AQjmsSession.java:429)
 at oracle.jms.AQjmsConnection.createTopicSession(AQjmsConnection.java:741)
 at com.dwidasa.StreamsEnq.main(StreamsEnq.java:40)
```

when passing this line :

> t_sess = t_conn.createTopicSession(true, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);

Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: Have you included a  `jdbc` driver in your  `CLASSPATH`? If yes Which version?

Comment: Please check https://community.oracle.com/thread/406640?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: I already follow the instruction from that link.
I use ojdbc-14.jar, aqapi.jar, and my Oracle version is 11.2

Comment: Please check this  `The older ojdbc14.jar that gave me problem was of the size 1 M but the latest one is of the size 1.5 M (approx).`

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-10201-088211.html

Comment: thank you, it has been working now.